# Proof of Lemma 6.15 in Mitzenmacher&Upfal "Probability and Computing"

Tags: probability, proof-verification, algorithms

The authors are showing how Lovasz local lemma can be used to derive a Monte Carlo algorithm for the k-SAT problem. 
My problem is with the end of the proof of Lemma 6.15 and it may not be related with the core of the proof.

The authors show that the probability that the graph $H'$ has a connected component of size $r$ is upper bounded by 
$$md^{8r/d^3}((d+1)2^{-k/2})^{r/d^3} \;\; (1)$$
and they upper-bound this quantity with 
$$m 2^{(rk/d^3)(8 \alpha + 2 \alpha - 1/2)},  \;\; (2)$$
concluding that if $r\ge c \log_2 m$ for large enough $c$ and small enough $\alpha >0$, this quantity is $o(1)$ as $m$ increases.
My problem is how to prove that $(1)\le (2)$. The only inequality for $d$ is  $d\le k 2^{\alpha k}$. Considering $d+1 \le d^2$ and the bound for $d$, I obtain
$$md^{8r/d^3}((d+1)2^{-k/2})^{r/d^3} \le m 2^{(rk/d^3)(10 \alpha + 10\frac{\log_2 k}{k} - 1/2)},$$
but now the exponent is no more negative independently from how small $\alpha >0 $ is.

Any help is welcome.